# Mapping objects with JAXB generated non-public list fields and missing setters with ModelMapper

Tags: java, jaxb, mapping, modelmapper

I have data structures generated by jaxb. Parts of the structures are basically identical but they are in different namespaces and therefore the generated Java types are different.

I need to transfer data between these structures. In the project ModelMapper is used for mapping so I am expected to use that.

My problem is that ModelMapper can't map the lists generated for 'maxOccurs="unbounded"' elements.

Let's say I have the following schema:

```
<xs:complexType name="CityData">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="districtData" type="DistrictData" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="DistrictData">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="population" type="xs:int" nillable="false" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

I have this schema in namespacea and in namespaceb so
Jaxb generates the following types into package namespacea and into package namespaceb:

```
public class CityData {
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected List<DistrictData> districtData;
    //... jaxb explanation why there's no setter
    public List<DistrictData> getDistrictData() {
        if (districtData == null) {
            districtData = new ArrayList<DistrictData>();
        }
        return this.districtData;
    }
}

public class DistrictData {
    protected int population;
    public int getPopulation() {
        return population;
    }
    public void setPopulation(int value) {
        this.population = value;
    }
}
```

Now If I create a source CityData from package namespacea and ask modelmapper to map it to a destination CityData in namespaceb then the data is not mapped:

```
    CityData cityData = new CityData();
    DistrictData districtData = new DistrictData();
    districtData.setPopulation(1234);
    cityData.getDistrictData().add(districtData);

    ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();
    modelMapper.getConfiguration().setMatchingStrategy(MatchingStrategies.STRICT);

    namespaceb.CityData dest = modelMapper.map(cityData, namespaceb.CityData.class);
    System.out.println("dest.districtData: " + dest.getDistrictData());
```

result is:

```
dest.districtData: []
```

In other words, districtData is not copied to destination.

I understand that ModelMapper does not find a setter for districtData and therefore not map it. I read that one can reconfigure Jaxb to generate setters for list properties, but the jaxb object generation is not in my hand in the project.

So I would like to find out if there is a nice solution for the mapping with ModelMapper, or maybe with other mapper library in these cases.

I've created a mini project: https://github.com/riskop/ModelMapperJaxb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you just need to enable **FieldMatching** and set the access level of the fields to match to handle the missing setter. Check this configuration:

```
modelMapper.getConfiguration()
    .setMatchingStrategy(MatchingStrategies.STRICT)
    .setFieldMatchingEnabled(true)
    .setFieldAccessLevel(AccessLevel.PROTECTED);
```

Javadoc:

[setFieldAccessEnabled](http://modelmapper.org/javadoc/org/modelmapper/config/Configuration.html#setFieldMatchingEnabled-boolean-)

> Sets whether field matching should be enabled. When true, mapping may take place between accessible fields. Default is false.

[setFieldAccessLevel](http://modelmapper.org/javadoc/org/modelmapper/config/Configuration.html#setFieldAccessLevel-org.modelmapper.config.Configuration.AccessLevel-)

> Indicates that fields should be eligible for matching at the given accessLevel.
> **Note**: Field access is only used when field matching is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

I had a rough idea of a clumsy workaround with ModelMapper.Converter facility before reading pirho's answer. I think that pirho's answer is better (accepted) but for the record, below is the Converter workaround. This is basically manually defining the conversion for the substructures where there is no setter:

```
CountryData countryData = new CountryData();
CityData cityData = new CityData();
DistrictData districtData = new DistrictData();
districtData.setPopulation(1234);
cityData.getDistrictData().add(districtData);
countryData.getCityData().add(cityData);

ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();
modelMapper.getConfiguration().setMatchingStrategy(MatchingStrategies.STRICT);

modelMapper.addConverter(new Converter<CountryData, namespaceb.CountryData>() {
    @Override
    public namespaceb.CountryData convert(MappingContext<CountryData, namespaceb.CountryData> context) {
        namespaceb.CountryData result = new namespaceb.CountryData();
        if(context.getSource() != null) {
            for(CityData cityData : context.getSource().getCityData()) {
                namespaceb.CityData mapped = modelMapper.map(cityData, namespaceb.CityData.class);
                result.getCityData().add(mapped);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
});

modelMapper.addConverter(new Converter<CityData, namespaceb.CityData>() {
    @Override
    public namespaceb.CityData convert(MappingContext<CityData, namespaceb.CityData> context) {
        namespaceb.CityData result = new namespaceb.CityData();
        if(context.getSource() != null) {
            for(DistrictData districtData : context.getSource().getDistrictData()) {
                namespaceb.DistrictData mapped = modelMapper.map(districtData, namespaceb.DistrictData.class);
                result.getDistrictData().add(mapped);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
});

namespaceb.CountryData destCountryData = modelMapper.map(countryData, namespaceb.CountryData.class);
assertEquals(1, destCountryData.getCityData().size());
namespaceb.CityData destCityData = destCountryData.getCityData().get(0);
assertEquals(1, destCityData.getDistrictData().size());
namespaceb.DistrictData destDistrictData = destCityData.getDistrictData().get(0);
assertEquals(1234, destDistrictData.getPopulation());
```